# Is there a verb for whacking your head?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's a noun/verb for whacking yourself on the head?

I vaguely recall having seen a word for this somewhere but I'm not that sure. The closest phrase I can think of is **self harm** or **self mutilation**, but those aren't really what I'm looking for.

**I'd actually like something that can be used to convey someone's frustration**, i.e. something like a **[facepalm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facepalm)**.

It doesn't have to fit within the religious context.

Comment: If you'd actually like a word that conveys the idea of hitting oneself out of frustration (as in the TV commercial "I could have had a V8!") and not in a religious context, then this picture parodying monks "mortifying their flesh" is not relevant at all.

Comment: or self-punishment.....http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/self-punishment

Comment: @TimRomano - I think we should agree to introduce the phrase *"having a V8"*, or "V8-ing" - (As in:  "The child expresses his frustration with repeated **vee-eighting**) and see if it makes it into DSM 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a form of [self-flagellation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-flagellation):

> - beating with a whip or strap or rope as a form of punishment

The Free Dictionary

[The Flagellation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-flagellation):

> - refers in a Christian context to the Flagellation of Christ, an episode in the Passion of Christ prior to Jesus' crucifixion. The practice of mortification of the flesh for religious purposes was utilized by some Christians throughout most of Christian history, especially in Catholic monasteries and convents.

Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

The Scots use heid-banger as the noun of a person who heid-bangs, and heid-banging as the gerund.